# Single sign on Google

Tags: google-signin

How does the Google single sign on works (OR any website's SSO)?
For example, once I login to the Gmail, it lets me see "My places" on Google Maps without signing in again? Same with Yahoo mail and Yahoo notepad.

I am guessing this checking is done locally within the browser. But any more details would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is done with a cookie, that is accessible to all sub-sites on google, and it contains identification numbers. Then the sub-site queries the account server, gives the cookie, and the account server will return the user.

Actual implementation details may vary (as I am not a Google engineer), but I think you want to know how to do it, not what google does.

Comment: How does that explain YouTube?